# Can a MySQL Replica be setup with encrypted data at rest, while main is NOT encrypted

Tags: mysql

I have a production DB on which I need to set up data at rest encryption. It takes a while, leading to downtime. Can I set up a replica, let it replicate as is, then apply encryption on replica, while the main still remains as is?

Comment: Interesting question +1, but note that if your reads are strictly happening from the replicas, your proposed trick won't help, as the data won't be available anyway until it gets encrypted.

Comment: Yes, I would take the replica offline; one of the replicas. Encrypt it. then let it run and catch up.